# Class Name is not defined error in python

Tags: python

while i doing my python programming came across an error. code is given below.

```
import skfuzzy as fuzz
from skfuzzy import control as ctrl
f =fuzzy_()
print(f)
class fuzzy_:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def values(self,t = None, m = None, p = None):
```

> "the class name fuzzy_is not defined". Error shown.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to reorder it like this:

```py
import skfuzzy as fuzz
from skfuzzy import control as ctrl

class fuzzy_:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def values(self,t = None, m = None, p = None):

# First define the class
# Then instantiate it
f = fuzzy_()
print(f)
```

The python interpreter needs to find the class definition first while reading in the code from top-down. In your code example, the interpreter tried instantiating `fuzzy_` class object, but threw error as till then it had no idea of what `fuzzy_()` is.

Comment: Please consider choosing an answer as the **`accepted`** response. Thank you.

Comment: @NithinKm If you think this is the best answer here, please click on the tick mark right under the voting section and mark it as the **`accepted`** response. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

python interpreter reads from top to bottom, you are calling the instance of class before defining the class, move line 3 and 4 to the bottom after declaring the class and it should be fine.